# OpenJPA SynchronizeMappings in persistence.xml only to the managed tables

Tags: jpa, db2, openjpa, persistence.xml

I have read many tutorials about the SynchronizeMappings options in persistence.xml.
The configuration I have concluded is this one:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(SchemaAction=&apos;drop,create,add&apos;)"/>
```

This works fine in MySQL, but I have a problem with DB2 as it tries to drop some default tables (like SYS*)

So what I was wondering is the following:
Is is possible to tell OpenJPA to drop only the managed class entities and not all the tables of the database?

Thanks a lot